# How to tell what version of libfortran I need

Tags: gcc, g++, gnu, gfortran

I've been searching for quite a while for this answer, but I'm trying to find out what libgfortran versions correspond to the actual gfortran versions.

There is only 3 available and when I try to compile some code it tries to search for 5. I'm using g++/gfortran 8.3.1, so I'm not sure why its reaching for 5??

Could anyone help me out on what gfortran version corresponds to libgfortran5?

I'll have to ask a sys admin to install it, so if it's possible I'd rather just make it use libgfortran3 which is already there.

Answer (score 0):

The major version number for libgfortran is changed when the
ABI is changed.  This happens seldomly.  If gfortran 8.3.1 is
looking for libgfortran.so.5, then that is what you need.  I'll
note that the major version number has not changed in a long
time, and in fact, 5 is the version for all version of gfortran newer
than 8.3.1.  If you try to use libgfortran.so.3, you'll likely
have an unpleasant experience.